# Who was the mermaid at the end of Anansi Boys?

Tags: anansi-boys

The end end of Anansi Boys when

> Charlie and a boy sing at the beach

a mermaid arrives

> and sings with them.

The only other mention I can remember of a mermaid is Charlie remembering his father would "trick" him by saying "look a mermaid" when they walked at the beach, but young Charlie could never see the mermaid.

Is there something else I've missed about the mermaid?
I feel like I should know who it is, or is just completing

> Charlie's

journey, now he can see the mermaid?

Comment: Use the spoiler `>!` markdown to conceal spoilers in the body of the question, and use some clever wording (and _not_ a "spoiler!" disclaimer) for the title.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are correct in that the Mermaid is an indicator of Charlie's journey.  There are three mentions of "mermaid" in the book:

- Page 6: Charlie describes walks with his father in which his father would point out mermaids at the beach, which Charlie could never see, and accompanied by his embarrassment around his father's outgoing behavior and soft-shoe dancing in the sand.
- Page 93: When Grahame Coats demands Charlie's password, it turns out to be *mermaid*, m-e-r-m-a-i-d.
- Page 333: Charlie takes his son Marcus for a walk on the beach; they both see and sing with a mermaid, who reminisces about Charlie's father, and the scene ends with Charlie and Marcus both soft-shoe dancing in the sand.

Taken together, they tell the story of a man who subconsciously regretted his poor relationship with his father - even as he consciously pushed him away - and how he's mended that pattern with his son.  The mermaid can be taken as an embodiment of the sort of things that young Charlie found inexplicable and embarrassing about his father, but grew to understand and accept after his adventures.

Comment: I forgot about his password being Mermaid! Thanks for your answer